# ASP.NET: How do I avoid duplicating Seed Data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm seeding data while I develop my application using the seed method in the Configuration.cs file created under the migrations folder when automatic migrations were enabled. The problem is that when I use the "update-database" command after changing or adding new models, it re-seeds the data adding double entries everywhere. Then I have to go through and delete everything in all tables manually. My SQL server is a separate Azure instance.

How do I avoid duplication?

```
namespace ChangeApp.Migrations
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
    using Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ChangeIT.Models.ChangeContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ChangeIT.Models.ChangeContext context)
        {
            var people = new List<Person>
            {
                new Person { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Monroe", email = "david.bernstein@bdpint.com", manager = false, admin = false },
                new Person { FirstName = "Millard", LastName = "Fillmore", email = "dennis.yu@bdpint.com", manager = false, admin = false },
                new Person { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Adams", email = "jason.bullock@bdpint.com", manager = true, admin = false }
            };
            people.ForEach(s => context.people.Add(s));

            context.SaveChanges();

            var managers = new List<Manager>
            {
                new Manager { EngineerId = 3 }
            };

            managers.ForEach(s => context.managers.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                if (db.Roles.Count() == 0)
                {
                    var roles = new List<IdentityRole>
                {
                    new IdentityRole("Admin"),
                    new IdentityRole("Manager"),
                    new IdentityRole("User")
                };
                    roles.ForEach(s => db.Roles.Add(s));
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

            }


            var statuses = new List<Status>
            {
                new Status { StatusName = "Approved" },
                new Status { StatusName = "Pending Approval" },
                new Status { StatusName = "Completed" },
                new Status { StatusName = "Denied" }
            };

            statuses.ForEach(s => context.statuses.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var systems = new List<SystemDetail>
            {
                new SystemDetail { SystemName = "Citrix" },
                new SystemDetail { SystemName = "VMWare" },
                new SystemDetail { SystemName = "SQL" }
            };

            systems.ForEach(s => context.systems.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var changes = new List<Change>
            {
                new Change { EngineerId = 1, ManagerId = 3, ChangeDescription = "Update Chrome to version 52", ChangeDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-19 "), ChangeTime = DateTime.Parse("16:20"), SystemDetailId = 1, StatusId = 1 },
                new Change { EngineerId = 2, ManagerId = 4, ChangeDescription = "Put Cluster 1 blade 36 in maintenance mode. Replace memory in slot 2", ChangeDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-08-26"), ChangeTime = DateTime.Parse("16:20"),SystemDetailId = 2, StatusId = 2 }
            };

            changes.ForEach(s => context.changes.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AddOrUpdate()` method is intended for exactly this use.

You could still have issues if not all of your properties are explicitly stated in the Seed method. For instance if you would assign a GUID field in the constructor or a random number.

The `AddOrUpdate()` will check all the properties in the model and create a new entry in the DB if not all the properties match.

Answer (score 3):

Just add to beginning in Seed method:

```
 if (context.people.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }
```

Comment: That's probably a good approach but if you add to the Seed method it will break.

Comment: @illug, why it will break? I saw it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro#add-code-to-initialize-the-database-with-test-data

Comment: If you want to add new records to the people table using the Seed method, the new records will not be added unless you delete everything from the table before running the Seed method since .Any() will check only if it contains any records at all.

Comment: @illug, yes, but I don't think he adds new records every time during migration.

Comment: No, most likely not. Maybe my English is getting in the way :)

What I meant with the original comment was that if you want more data into the DB using the Seed method then using .Any will force you to delete from the table first. Using .AddOrUpdate will work nicely though. That being said, I am not even sure .AddOrUpdate is available in EF Core.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
context.people.AddOrUpdate()
```